# elasticsearch docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to run elasticsearch 8.3.3 using docker-compose. I'm getting an Error.

**Below is the docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: els
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.3-arm64
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/datafile
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - elastcinetwork

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.3.3-arm64
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - els
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200
    networks:
      - elastcinetwork

networks:
  elastcinetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Process 'docker compose  -f "docker-compose.yml" config --s...' exited with code 15
Error: service "kibana" depends on undefined service els: invalid compose project
```

Answer (score 0):

You should depends on 'service name' rather than on container name

```
depends_on:
  - elasticsearch
```